# Mutate a transposed column into new columns row-wise by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have grouped data like follows:

```
  group id var
1     1  1   1
2     1  2   0
3     1  3   1
4     2  1   0
5     2  2   1
6     3  1   0
```

I'd like to create N new `var` columns (`var1`, `var2`,...) where N is the max number of individuals in a group (in this case N = 3 as largest group is `group 1` which has three `id`s.

`var1` should contain the `var` value for `id = 1` in each group; likewise `var2` should contain the `var` value for each `id = 2` in each group. Where the number of columns exceeds the number in a group it should return `NA`.

The sought output for the above example would be:

```
  group id var var1 var2 var3
1     1  1   1    1    0    1
2     1  2   0    1    0    1
3     1  3   1    1    0    1
4     2  1   0    0    1   NA
5     2  2   1    0    1   NA
6     3  1   0    0   NA   NA
```

**Example Code**

```
a <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
                id = c(1,2,3,1,2,1), 
                var = c(1,0,1,0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to pivot the dataframe wider: you can use `pivot_wider()`. If you want to keeps the original rows, you can also use `right_join()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% right_join(
  pivot_wider(a,values_from = var, names_from = id, names_prefix = "var"),
  by='group'
)
```

Output:

```
  group id var var1 var2 var3
1     1  1   1    1    0    1
2     1  2   0    1    0    1
3     1  3   1    1    0    1
4     2  1   0    0    1   NA
5     2  2   1    0    1   NA
6     3  1   0    0   NA   NA
```

However, maybe is this a bit redundant? Just using `pivot_wider()` keeps the same info because `varx` are the original `id` column:

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = var, names_from = id, names_prefix = "var")

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  group  var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0     1
2     2     0     1    NA
3     3     0    NA    NA
```

Comment: Here is a version with `names_glue`: `df %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = var, 
              names_from = id, 
              names_glue = "var{id}")`